# Change regionmap chart colouring option

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have some VBA code to insert a RegionMap chart in excel. The code then changes the range of the series' data (I did this because the chart entry directly for the region I need, for some reason was not working properly). I also have the The code to change the chart title. All these work properly. However I cannot find the code to change the way that countries are coloured. By default they are coloured based on series' values, but I want to colour them based on secondary categories. When I try to record a macro, I get an empty record. Any ideas?

My code so far

```
    Range("A9:A13,C9:C13").Select
    Range("C9").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(494, xlRegionMap).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Heatmap!$B$9:$B$13"
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Caption = "Top Keywords"
```

This is the data

[image]

This is what I get

[image]

This is what I need

[image]

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and changing the colors? That way you know how the code would look like.

Comment: I did and got the below which doesn't help me to change the type of the series visualisation: ```ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
        .SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopColor.RGB = 255
        .SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopColor.Transparency = 0
    End With```

Comment: Looks like there is no way to code this change. My only workaround is to insert the graph manually and change it manually to show by categories. Then Leave it there and it will be updated as the values change each time ne data are added. If needed, it will have to be manually adjusted to a different range